# Entity registration, register to more event from one form in event detail

Tags: entities

Hi I have created special content type called Event. It is simillar to facebook events. It has description, address where it will be held and date when it will be held. I succesfully added there registration form with Entity registration. So now I can register to one event. But I want to be able to register from one event to more events like this.

[image: screenshot]

In event detail, registration form section, I want to have checkboxes. When I click on these checkboxes and click on register to event, it will register me to every clicked event, and to opened event too. These additional event, I will select in administration, when creating new event.

Answer (score 2):

Install [VBO](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, create a entity view with checkboxes. See the Rules sections [here](https://drupal.org/node/1463042). You can use that rule in VBO to register them automatically to the Events they selected.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail into how this works exactly?

Comment: I'm trying two separate views - one content based and the other registration based. The registration based one allows the use of that rule, but when I try to organize it, it shows the active registrations.

Comment: How do you get the additional fields at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I found no solution to this problem, and so I had to write a custom module, which is just about finished. I will post the link to the Drupal.org location when it is finished.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Do you happen to have the link to your module?

Comment: No, I left the source with an old company I worked for and I don't think I have it anywhere. VBO (maybe with a custom function) should be able to do this, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use conditional fields to make multiple work flows.

For example, make your type of events as drop-down from taxonomy reference. Then each option value has a conditional field is possible.

But if you need completely different forms itself you can do this by creating registration types and add fields accordingly.

You can make a registration type switching in content type creation and which enables users to select the right event to register.

-- Najeem M Illyas