# Fillable Fields in a View

Tags: views

I want to submit several items with Views Bulk Operations - is there a module or method to add fillable fields to a view?

Comment: Your going to have to elaborate on what you are trying to do. As it stands your question does not give us enough to go on.

Comment: Ok, so I'm using the entity registration module, which attaches a registration entity to a particular node (in this case, content type = event). I'm using Views Bulk Operations in order to submit a select box to a rule, which will then create an entity, based on the item selected. However, I want additional information (like email, first name, etc) to be collected as well, including for anonymous users.

Comment: Similar to this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78453/entity-registration-register-to-more-event-from-one-form-in-event-detail

Answer (score -1):

I think you need editablefield module. once this module is enable you can set any fields editable in your view. So when you visit your view page or block you can edit the field value there itself..
Nice Ajax is implemented in here, so it works very nice.. You can set it like double click to edit..

NOTE - I am not able to link the module with original URL at drupal.org so you can search for it in google with same name.

Comment: The problem is that that leads to repeated fields for first name, last name, etc. I only want one of these, as it is meant for a bulk registration form.

Comment: You have asked for fillable field in view & this is exact solution for that. You can't create make apear a node into view without createing it..so there is no meaning in bulk creation of node by view..

Comment: I'm creating an entity by a rule by Views Bulk Operations. I just want to include 5 fillable fields that a user can enter before selecting Views Bulk Operation submitter.